# How to load local images in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I found from the tensorflow documentation that the code to load a dataset named "flower_photos " is

> data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
>                                            fname='flower_photos', untar=True)

I'm having some images in my local machine and want to load and use it for doing some neural network algorithms like CNN. How to load and preprocess a locally stored image in tensorflow?

Comment: Did you made it with the assistance i provided?

Comment: Yes. But I found that with the basic python image preprocessing its easy to achieve, the reason may be I m a beginner.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

This is done by the Image Preprocessing features from Keras.

I will provide some explanation regarding an example from the Keras Documentation (Please [read the docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for further Information.)

This preprocessing provides a pipeline for the training and there is a `.flow_from_directory()`-method to read from the local filesystem.

In this example from the docs, the pictures are augmented by flipping them horizontally and applying a shear-range and zoom-range of 0.2. The rescaling is done to normalize the RGB-Values to a range from 0 to 1:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

With this ImageDataGenerator you use the `.fit_generator()`-method (instead of `.fit()`) to use this prepared pipeline to flow in you model processing.

steps_per_epoch * batch_size should equal to the size of your training data.
validation_steps * batch_size should equal to the size of your validation data.